# Swift 3 casting or NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, casting, numberformatter

Is there any advantage to using a NumberFormatter over simply casting?
For example 1 and 2 below both seem to do the same job, but casting seems to be easier to read so why would the NumberFormatter often be used in code samples I've found?

```
var displayValue: Double? {
    get {
        if let text = display.text,
        // 1 let value = NumberFormatter().number(from: text)?.doubleValue
        // 2 let value = Double(text)
}
```

Comment: Huge difference. `NumberFormatter` handles fully localized numbers including proper decimal separator and grouping separators.

Comment: If this number is to be shown/captured in the UI, `NumberFormatter` will localize it properly, whereas `Double(text)` may not be able to handle it properly. E.g. if a German user enters `3,14`, `NumberFormatter` will correctly interpret that as `3.14`, whereas `Double(text)` won't. Bottom line, if converting to and from strings for the UI, `NumberFormatter` is prudent. If not (e.g. for parsing numbers represented as strings in JSON), then `Double(text)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge difference. If you want something to handle:

- Thousand-digit separator and decimal places: one million is commonly written as `1,000,000` in the US, `1.000.000` in France, and `10,00,000` in India.
- Currency symbol: `$100` or `£100` or `€100`
- Negative numbers in the accounting style, for example -100 is written as `(100)` (and often in red too)
- Percentage: 5% → 0.05
- Word spelling: "one hundred six" → 106

etc... then use `NumberFormatter`.